# Select value of tag in HTML with Microsoft Agility Pack

Tags: html-agility-pack

I have html code with this element.

```
<span itemprop="datePublished" content="2016-06-18T00:44:00+06:00">০০:৪৫, জুন ১৮, ২০১৬</span>
```

With `Agility Pack` I want value "2016-06-18T00:44:00+06:00" of Attribute `content`. I can select InnerText with this code:

```
HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@itemprop='datePublished']");
```

Comment: Typo? ➔ span itemprop="**publishDate**" vs @itemprop='**datePublished**' `?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GetAttributeValue(attrName, defaultVal)` method which return attribute value of name `attrName` if it exists, and return `defaultVal` otherwise :

```cs
var span = HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@itemprop='datePublished']");
var content = span.GetAttributeValue("content", "");
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can do it like getting value from dictionary : `var content = span.Attributes["content"].Value;`. Notice though that this will throw exception in case the `span` doesn't have attribute of name 'content'...